# Static files are served locally but not through nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, node.js

I'm running a node.js API on a VPS, which is served by nginx on Ubuntu 13.04.

I'm using [restify](http://restify.com/) and serving static files like this:

```
server.get(
  /\/static\/?.*/,
  restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname   // => /home/misha/rxviz-api
  })
);
```

Here is the relevant bits from nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.rxviz.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4010/;
    }
}
```

(full config is [here](https://gist.github.com/moroshko/80f957ad29ee2bf7d01199fca29b87b3#file-nginx-conf-L55-L72))

When running:

```
curl http://localhost:4010/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json
```

on the VPS, I get the contents of `test.json`.

However, when navigating to:

```
http://api.rxviz.com/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json
```

in a browser, I get 404.

nginx error logs show that `/opt/nginx/html/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json` not found.

Why does nginx trying to access `test.json` in `/opt/nginx/html` rather than `/home/misha/rxviz-api`?

Few more points:

- `static` directory permissions are `drwxrwxr-x`
- I can access `http://api.rxviz.com/` in the browser successfully

Comment: Does the home directory (all parents to static dir actually) have x permission for nginx user?

Comment: I can access `http://api.rxviz.com/` in the browser

Comment: That URL has nothing to do with the home directory

Comment: Sorry, you are right. `home` is `drwxr-xr-x`, `misha` is `drwxr-xr-x`, and `rxviz-api` is `drwxrwxr-x`.

Comment: Just noticed that `home` is the only one under the `root` user: `drwxr-xr-x   3 root  4096 Jul 15  2013 home`. All the rest are under the `misha` user (e.g. `drwxrwxr-x  8 misha     4096 Jun 14 07:00 rxviz-api`). Is this a problem?

Comment: Hm, the permissions should be fine. And as I understand nginx matching rules the location order also does not matter here.

Comment: Just to be sure there is a file `/home/misha/rxviz-api/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json` and it is readable by the nginx user?

Comment: In general, user home directories are not a suitable place to store files for web service on the server.

Comment: @eckes Yes: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 misha 20 Jun 14 06:42 /home/misha/rxviz-api/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json`

Comment: @eckes I updated the question. Looks like nginx is trying to access `/opt/nginx/html/static/` for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm, you removed the static location from your question, what is the actual complete config you are using? If it accesses /opt/nginx then it resolves the resources according to the root, so no location rule matches.

Comment: Make sure you do not have any regular expression locations, they will overwrite your prefix rules. You can stop that with `location ^~ /static` I think.

Comment: @eckes My understanding is that, nginx is pointing to the locally running node server, which is serving the static files. Do I still need `location /static/ { ... }` i the nginx config? My full config is [here](https://gist.github.com/moroshko/80f957ad29ee2bf7d01199fca29b87b3#file-nginx-conf-L55-L72).

Comment: It would be good to have nginex serve the static files that's much faster. If you only have the proxy location then node would serve them. However since nginex does not pass the requests on there is surely a regular expression matching those URLs instead

Comment: @eckes Do you mean regex matching in my node server or in nginx? (Just to remind, I can access `curl http://localhost:4010/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json` successfully.)

Comment: A regular expression in nginex would capture all matched requests - it will neither forward to request to the proxy location nor to a /static prefix. Your optional static location and the / proxy pass need the `^~` qualifier to immediately match